# Callback'и в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно написать функцию `askPassword(success, failure)`, которая спрашивает у пользователя логин и пароль и проверяет его правильность. Пароль считается правильным, если в нём содержится ровно три английские гласные буквы (гласными считать буквы `['a','e','i','o','u','y']`) и ровно такой же набор согласных (все буквы, кроме перечисленных шести `['b','c','d','f','g','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','z']`), как в логине. Порядок и количество согласных также должно совпадать. Считается, что логин и пароль написаны в нижнем регистре.

***Пример: для логина “login” подойдут пароли “aaalgn” и “luagon“.***

Если пароль правильный, функция должна вызвать коллбэк `success`, передав ему в качестве аргумента логин. А если пароль был неверный - `failure`, передав ему в качестве аргументов логин и сообщение об ошибке (в таком порядке). Сообщение об ошибке должно быть одним из трёх вариантов:

- “`Wrong number of vowels`”, если в пароле неверное число гласных;
- “`Wrong consonants`”, если в пароле набор согласных отличается от
  набора согласных логина;
- “`Everything is wrong`”, если оба условия нарушены.

Также напишите функцию `main()`, которая вызывает написанную функцию так, чтобы в случае успеха она печатала “`Привет, {логин}!`”, а в случае ошибки – “`Кто-то пытался притвориться пользователем {логин}, но в пароле допустил ошибку: {текст ошибки, большими буквами}.`”. Основная проблема в том, что я не могу правильно сформулировать if'ы:

```
def askPassword(success, failure):
    GLASNIE = ['a','e','i','o','u','y']
    SOGLASNIE = ['b','c','d','f','g','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','z']
    login = input()
    password = input()
    if : # в пароле неверное число гласных
        failure = 'Wrong number of vowels'
        return failure
    elif : # в пароле набор согласных отличается от набора согласных логина
        failure = 'Wrong consonants'
        return failure
    elif : # оба условия нарушены
        failure = 'Everything is wrong'
        return failure
    else:
        success = login
        failure = 0
        return success, failure

def main():
    askPassword(success, failure)
    if failure == 0:
        print('Привет,',success+'!')
    elif failure != 0:
        print(failure)
main()
```

Comment: *"Callback'и в Python"* -- это чересчур расплывчатый заголовок для задачи, описанной в вопросе. Используйте более информативные заголовки, более специфичные для вашего конкретного вопроса. [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно пройтись по паролю циклом и записывать количество гласных \ согласных:

```
vowel, consonant = 0, 0
for ch in password:
    vowel += ch in GLASNIE
    consonant += ch in SOGLASNIE

if vowel != 3 and consonant != 3:
    failure = 'Everything is wrong'
    return failure
elif vowel != 3:
    failure = 'Wrong number of vowels'
    return failure
elif consonant != 3:
    failure = 'Wrong consonants'
    return failure
else:
    success = login
    failure = 0
    return success, failure
```

Comment: Способ хороший, но не очень удовлетворяет условию

Comment: Изменил '>' на '!=' - теперь должен удовлетворять больше